# How can i extract the numerical value ($54,857.85) from this given html parse tree?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've been trying to learn web scraping using Python BeautifulSoup. However, I'm running into some trouble with my code, as it does not allow me to simply access this value using this code:

```
value = doc.find_all(class_="bg-theme-p-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-theme-text")
print(value)
```

[This is the html tree image of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tekqw.png)

where result.text is basically the html address that I have accessed through requests module.

The print(value) entry doesn't return anything, instead prints out the result [].
How can i access all the relevant values which have the class as written above?

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: https://poolsv1.tracer.finance/pools/

Comment: I suggest you `print(doc)` to see the HTML returned. It will probably be different from what you see in a browser

Comment: Yes I just did so and it definitely doesnt return me any of the tags that have the numerical values of those cryptocurrencies. What is the problem here? If i can access them, how would I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use stripped_strings property:;

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print ' '.join(soup.find('td', {'class': 'bg-theme-p-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-theme-text'}).stripped_strings)
```

Comment: I just tried it again with this code but still doesnt seem to work. It doesn't return any value, with 'None' returned as a result.

Comment: I tried again using this code, but returns that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Stripped_strings'. Is this website even scrapable?

https://poolsv1.tracer.finance/pools/